# How are image uploads done in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I want to send text and an image to a blog post API endpoint that accept a text (required ) and an image ( optional ). I am able to `POST` a new blog post when I fill in a textarea only but unable to send an image in the `POST` body. Here's the form fields

```
<label for="comment" class="sr-only">Write what's on your mind</label>

<textarea
    v-model="form.post"
    rows="3"
    name="comment"
></textarea>

<label>
  <input ref="file" type="file" v-on:change="onImageUpload(e)" />
</label>
```

In my script setup

```
<script setup>
    import { ref } from "vue";
    
    const form = ref({
      post: null,
      file: null
    });
    
    function onImageUpload() {
        console.log(file.value.files);
        // form.value.file = form.value.file[0]; 
        // console.log("selected file", form.value);
    }
</script>
```

This code returns the error below

> Uncaught ReferenceError: file is not defined

How can I access the image file being uploaded and pass it along inside the `form.value`?

Comment: I think you want to access file from `form` ref. Then try `form.file.value....`.

Comment: @ZeyarPaing I tried doing that but got the error `Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "value", form.file is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

My way of handling file input is that I receive the file from `onChange` of the input. And store the file as a state in `data`
This is how I implement.

```
  <input
        @change="handleFileInput"
        type="file"
        accept="image/jpeg, image/png"
  />

  data: () => ({
    file: null,
  }),

  methods: {
    handleFileInput(e) {
      this.file = e.target.files[0];
    }
  }
```

In your code, you tried to pass e from onChange, but you don't need to do this for just passing event object. Try adding a parameter that accept the event object and use that object to get access to chosen files. This might be different from your approach with refs, but it just works.